# Avoid overlapping with android:layout_centerVertical="true" in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

[edit]

Given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:background="#ff00ff00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#ffff0000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I avoid the overlapping between text1 and text2 on small screens. Important:

- if possible with no overlapping, text2 should be displayed exactly in the vertical center of the screen
- if there is overlapping, text2 should move down a bit and be displayed directly below text1

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to The child LinearLayout. This will make it center of the parent.

Change  to  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`  of button_container. This will make it fill the remaining height of the parent. Your code would look something like this after the change :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff0000"
    android:text="TextView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but here the button_container is in the middle of the remaining space, not in the middle of the screen. I need it exactle in the middle of the screen (if enough space is available).

Comment: you have changed the whole question and all attempted answers have become out of context now. Please ask it as a separate question.